# Simple Perl Regular Expression SAS

Tags: regex, sas

I am working on some RTF code generation. I am using following code that is working fine but i am not well in PRX functions.

Is there any way to simplyfy my code?

Code:

```
data _null_;
   length tmptxt $100.;
   tmptxt="a\b Refer $crossref(Table 1) and $italic.Section $crossref(3.1)$enditalic";
   tmptxt=prxchange('s/([\\{}])/\\$1/',-1,tmptxt);
   tmptxt= prxchange('s/([\$][a-zA-Z]+)([\(])/%$1$2/',-1,tmptxt);
   tmptxt=prxchange('s/%\$/%/',-1,tmptxt);
   tmptxt=prxchange('s/([\$][a-zA-Z]+)/&$1$2/',-1,tmptxt);
   tmptxt=prxchange('s/&\$/&/',-1,tmptxt);
   put tmptxt;
run;
```

Thanks in advance.
Rajaram

Comment: I do not see a way to merge your replacements since the replacements differ in all of them. :(

Comment: Not seeing the `perl` link here?

Comment: @Sobrique: Maybe it should have been `pcre` instead?

Comment: The third seems to undo part of the second.  Is it truly necessary to do that?

Comment: @Joe I have modified further as follows remaining 'code' tmptxt=prxchange('s/[\$]([a-z]+)(?=\()/%$1/i',-1,tmptxt);
tmptxt=prxchange('s/[\$]([a-z]+)/&$1/i',-1,tmptxt);

Answer (score 0):

Not really.  There *may* be minor improvements that could be made to the regex's but it's not really going to have a noticeable impact.

I'd leave it as it is.